# Having problems writing to text files. Text files being overwritten/cut

Tags: python, text-files, fwrite, truncate, prepend

I would like to write new data to the beginning of my text file, with the previous data shifting down 1 line each time new data is imported, I would like everything to be organized, but every time I import something gets deleted.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

response = requests.get('https://www.lotteryusa.com/michigan/lucky-4-life/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
date = soup.find(class_='date')
results = soup.find(class_='draw-result list-unstyled list-inline')
d = datetime.strptime(date.time['datetime'], '%Y-%m-%d')
Lucky = (d.strftime("%m%d%Y")+(',')+results.get_text()[:-20].strip().replace('\n',','))
print(Lucky)

with open("webscraper2noteppad++", "r+") as f:
    file = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0,0)
    f.write(Lucky)
```

Also tried doing this

```
with open("webscraper2noteppad++", "r+") as f:
    file = f.read()
    f.seek(0,0)
    f.write(Lucky + '\n')
```

but I have to put 10 lines between the already existing data, and the new data. So it can be can be imported on top without deleting.

Comment: Can you show expected file content?

Answer (score 0):

You can first read the content of your file, the append it to the new data and then write everything to the file:

```
with open("webscraper2noteppad++", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

with open("webscraper2noteppad++", "w") as f:
    f.write('{}{}{}'.format(lucky, '\n' if data else '', data))
```

Comment: This worked but it appended to the bottom, I would like to prepend it. Thanks for the help.